# Spark-graphx- Strongly connected components

Tags: spark-graphx

I'm new to spark and spark-graphx. I tried to run strongly connected components, but I'm getting only the triplets which are connected.

What I'm looking for here is getting all the vertices (group of vertices),  which are only strongly connected (including single nodes).

**Example:**

```
Vertex  Edge    description

1       2       rule1 
1       3       rule1 
2       3       rule1 
3       4       rule1 
4       5       rule1 
5       6       rule1 
5       7       rule1 
9       10      rule2 
10      11      rule2 
10      12      rule2
```

**Output of strongly connected components:**

```
(1,2,3) - Rule1
(4) - Rule1
(5,6,7)- Rule1
(9,10,11,12)- Rule2
```

I believe I explained the use case correctly, please let me know if you need further details.

The final goal is to assign one user defined Id to each strongly connected group.

Answer (score 0):

I use PySpark and if I try your example probably I will get the output in DataFrame format as following:

```
+---------------+
|id | component |
+---+-----------+
|1  |rule1      |
|2  |rule1      |
|3  |rule1      |
|4  |rule1      |
|5  |rule1      |
|6  |rule1      |
|7  |rule1      |
|9  |rule2      |
|10 |rule2      |
|11 |rule2      |
|12 |rule2      |
+---+-----------+
```

As you may know, PySpark is Python API which still interprets Scala scripts. I have no idea why Scala prints the result in separate lines (maybe because mapReduce applies the algorithm in parallel and once convergence is reached it prints out the output). However I think you can aggregate the result and say 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are strongly connected and belong to rule1 group. And 10,11,12 belong to rule2.